# How to trigger a restart in Brunch's preCompile hook so it reloads the brunch-config.js file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, hook, restart, brunch

I've written a quite complex `brunch-config.js` configuration file that modifies these arrays at the start:

- `paths.watched` and,
- `files.javascripts / stylesheets` (the *joinTo* "filename" => /patterns/).

What I'd like to do is to restart Brunch when it detects a particular change.

I've got a specific file (acts like a flag to set focus on a specific watch-folder) that can be moved around, and in doing so I'd like the above arrays to re-populate different data based on the special file relocation.

Regarding brunch's built-in restart mechanism, I'm not sure how far it goes (ie: when it's reinstalling NPM modules, or when the `brunch-config.js` file itself is modified). But if that causes a full reload of the `brunch-config.js` - How can I trigger this restart functionality via NodeJS code executed within the configuration file, more specifically in the "**preCompile**" hook?

Here's how it looks like so far in action:
[image]

Comment: Touching `brunch-config` should work pretty well. What's the reason of not using it?

Comment: I would prefer to avoid changing code to trigger the update - reason being, by moving the file I'm tracking in my complex setup, it should suffice as an action to invoke a restart (from where I'm running a timer to poll the location of this special file).

Comment: Attaching a GIFCam capture of my setup to show what I mean.

Comment: Brunch does not have such functionality built-in. Although you don't need to "change code" — just execute an action similar to unix `touch` util — just touch the config without changing the contents

Comment: Got this to work by using `nodemon`. Instead of starting brunch directly, I start watching for the specific file extension in the `app` folder, and starts with the `--exec "brunch watch --server"` command.